# Problema al agregar SUM() en query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta Query SQL pero al querer agregar un `SUM` a la columna `CANT_DISPONIBLE` me genera error, esta es mi Query

```
select EB.ARTICULO,EB.BODEGA,EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE,EB.CANT_RESERVADA
,EB.CANT_TRANSITO,EB.CANT_REMITIDA,SUM(EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE) X
from EXISTENCIA_BODEGA EB,ARTICULO CL
where 
 EB.ARTICULO=CL.ARTICULO AND
(EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE>0 or EB.CANT_REMITIDA>0 or 
 EB.CANT_TRANSITO>0 or EB.CANT_RESERVADA>0)
and (SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,1)='T'
OR SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)='VM'
OR SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)='CS')
and SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)<>'TA'
AND CL.CLASIFICACION_1  IN ('1010','1007')
order by EB.BODEGA
```

El error es por el:

```
Group By: Column 'EXISTENCIA_BODEGA.ARTICULO'
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Te falta agrupar (group by) por las demás columnas que forman parte de la sentencia.

Comment: @Rosendo Ropher entonces debo quitar el order by? si lo cambio por el group by no afecta?

Comment: Puedes dejarlo si es prioritario ordenar de alguna manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando utilizas una función de agregado (como SUM) en una SQL los campos de la SELECT que no estén incluidos en funciones de agregado deben especificarse en la cláusula GROUP BY.

La corrección de tu consulta depende de lo que quieras obtener.

Por ejemplo si lo que quieres es obtener las sumas de las cantidades para cada artículo y bodega:

```
    SELECT EB.ARTICULO, EB.BODEGA, 
        SUM(EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE),SUM(EB.CANT_RESERVADA), 
        SUM(EB.CANT_TRANSITO), SUM(EB.CANT_REMITIDA), 
        SUM(EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE) X
    FROM EXISTENCIA_BODEGA EB, ARTICULO CL
    WHERE 
        EB.ARTICULO=CL.ARTICULO AND
        (EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE>0 OR EB.CANT_REMITIDA>0 OR
            EB.CANT_TRANSITO>0 OR EB.CANT_RESERVADA>0)
        AND (SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,1)='T'
        OR SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)='VM'
        OR SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)='CS')
        AND SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)<>'TA'
        AND CL.CLASIFICACION_1  IN ('1010','1007')
    GROUP BY EB.ARTICULO, EB.BODEGA
    ORDER BY EB.BODEGA
```

Comment: Lo que intentaba hacer es la totalizar la columna CANT_DISPONIBLE, CANT_RESERVADA..., pero la anterior es por suma por fila verdad?

Comment: Si quieres sacar los totales deberías quitar los campos ARTICULO y BODEGA de la SELECT y eliminar las cláusulas GROUP BY y ORDER BY. Si lo que quieres es sacar los totales por BODEGA deberías quitar el campo ARTICULO de la SELECT y del GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentaba, solo te hace falta añadir la clausula `group by` (tal como lo indica el strace del error) ya que haz añadido la función `sum` en concreto tu consulta debe quedar así

```
SELECT EB.ARTICULO,
    EB.BODEGA,
    EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE,
    EB.CANT_RESERVADA ,
    EB.CANT_TRANSITO,
    EB.CANT_REMITIDA,
    SUM(EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE) X
FROM EXISTENCIA_BODEGA EB, ARTICULO CL
WHERE EB.ARTICULO            = CL.ARTICULO
AND (EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE      > 0
OR EB.CANT_REMITIDA          > 0
OR EB.CANT_TRANSITO          > 0
OR EB.CANT_RESERVADA         > 0)
AND (SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,1) = 'T'
OR SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)   = 'VM'
OR SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2)   = 'CS')
AND SUBSTRING(EB.BODEGA,1,2) <> 'TA'
AND CL.CLASIFICACION_1      IN ('1010','1007')
GROUP BY EB.ARTICULO,
    EB.BODEGA,
    EB.CANT_DISPONIBLE,
    EB.CANT_RESERVADA ,
    EB.CANT_TRANSITO,
    EB.CANT_REMITIDA
ORDER BY EB.BODEGA;
```

Comment: ok si funciono, y si quiero totalizar la columna como le haría, ya que del código anterior suma pero por fila, lo que quiero es que sume toda la columna @Rosendo Ropher

Comment: ¿Sin importar la bodega y demás columnas (en tu `select`)? ¿Solo totalizar?